# Ajax call with javascript fails with internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, cross-domain

OK here is my code which i am using to call a remote site for a list of data objects which i want to display on another site.

This works fine with Chrome and Firefox but throws error in IE "Permission denied"

I also added the request for Access-Control-Allow-Origin and headers but the issue persist in IE....

I can't use jQuery because the site on which I'll put this might not have jQuery. Does it have to something with cross domain request?

```
<script id= "sc1" type="text/javascript">
        function ajaxRequest() {
            var activexmodes = ["Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"]
            if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                for (var i = 0; i < activexmodes.length; i++) {
                    try {
                    return new ActiveXObject(activexmodes[i])
                        } catch (e) {
                    }
                }
            } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) return new XMLHttpRequest()
            else return false;
        }
        var contentDiv = document.createElement("div");
        contentDiv.id = 'contentJobsoid';
        document.getElementById('sc1').parentNode.appendChild(contentDiv);

        (function(){
            var mygetrequest = new ajaxRequest()
            if (mygetrequest.overrideMimeType) mygetrequest.overrideMimeType('text/html')
            mygetrequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (mygetrequest.readyState == 4) {
                    if (mygetrequest.status == 200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http") == -1) {
                        var data = mygetrequest.responseText;
                        document.getElementById("contentJobsoid").innerHTML = data;
                        } else {
                        console.log("An error has occured making the request");
                    }
                }
            }

            mygetrequest.open("GET", "http://www.demo.com/demo/dee0c7fe-867d-408d-a00f-d9bed4b169a7", true);
            mygetrequest.send(null);
            return false;
        }());
    </script> -->
```

Comment: You can put html in a site, but you can't use jQuery, because the site might not have jQuery? Why not include it, yourself, then?

Answer (score 0):

I just passed the data from the server in form of string in the script src tag and it solved my problem very easily